# Contact Form 7 Dropdown Force Required?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using Contact Form 7 to make a form for a client. I have made all fields required,including the selects (drop down) fields. However, the form is still being sent through when the drop down feilds aren't selected.

Is there any way to 'force' a field to be required? Has anyone come across this before? Do you know how to assist?

Here is my code:

```
 <label> Name: (Required)
[text* your-name] </label>

<label> Surname: (Required)
[text* your-name] </label>

<label> Contact Number: (Required)
[text* your-number] </label>

<label> Email Address: (Required)
[email* your-email] </label>

<label> Choose Branch: (Required)[select* recipient "Choose Branch:"
                "Johannesburg|christie@oonie.co.za"
                "Pretoria|christie@oonie.co.za"
                "Cape Town|christie@oonie.co.za"
                "Durban|christie@oonie.co.za"
                "Garden Route|christie@oonie.co.za"
                "Port Elizabeth|christie@oonie.co.za"
                "East London|christie@oonie.co.za"
                "Nelspruit|mchristie@oonie.co.za"
                "Vaal Triange|christie@oonie.co.za"]</label>

<label> Product: (Required)[select* product "Please select product:"
                "Product"
                "Product"
                "Product"
                "Product"
                "Product"
                "Product"
                "Product"
                "Product"]</label>

<label> Physical Address: (Required)
[text* your-area] </label>

<label> Size in Meters: (Required)
[text* your-area] </label>

<label> Enquiry
[textarea your-message class:bigger-textrea] </label>

[submit "Send"]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does the require work for the other fields? Is the form also being sent, if you leave a required text field empty?

Comment: Hi @jasie. All of the other required fields are working. It is only being sent if the Products are or aren't selected. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: For the form validator, "Please select product:" and "Choose Branch:" validate as filled out, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the form is being sent, because the select fields are indeed always filled out. You forgot the "include_blank" attribute:

```
[select* menu-834 include_blank "product 1" "product 2" "product 3"]
```

It inserts a blank item into the top of options of the drop-down menu which evaluates as not-filled-out.

See docs for `include_blank` option in drop-down menus:
 https://contactform7.com/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-menus/#select

Comment: Jasie, you are an absolute genius. It totally worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help :-)